# how to do async in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous

There is function which need to sleep 10 second. But in the meantime, I don't want it to block my main function. How to deal with that?
I try to do like that. However, it still block my main function.

```
def tester():
   pool.size=2;
   pool=multiprocessing.Pool(pool_size);
   pool.apply_async(send_mail, args=("test",));
   pool.close();
   pool.join();
   print "email is done";
```

the main function will call this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pool.join();

is your blocker. remove it to not block.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join

EDIT:

```
import threading 

print "start"
th = threading.Thread(target=tester)
th.daemon = False
print "thread start"
th.start()
print "executing other code"
```

Comment: Sorry, it works. The reason it doesn't show up is it seems like the main function end before the subprocess finish.

Comment: spin off your emails into a separate thread. by marking it as non-daemon the python program will not exit until it is finished. i added some sample code above

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using Pool. You are spawning 2 subprocesses to send a single email? What about just spawning a single process. The following should get you started. (I put a "sleep(30)" where you would actually call send_mail)

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep

def wrap_send_email(q, msg):
    try:
        sleep(30)
        q.put( [ msg, 'mail sent sucessfully'] )
    except: 
        q.put( [ msg, 'mail not sent successfully'] )


def test():
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=wrap_send_email, args=(q, 'test message'))
    p.start()
    while p.is_alive():
        print("Doing stuff while the other process is working.")
        sleep(5)
    print(q.get())
    p.join()
```

Comment: The reason of blocking is join().

Comment: Yes. I was perhaps misunderstanding what you were trying to achieve. You have the statement, `print "email is done"` after the join. If you remove the join, that statement will execute immediately and not necessarily after the email is done. I also am not sure why you need a pool of 2 for this application. A pool of 1 seems sufficient, in which case, why use a `Pool` at all, just use a `Process.`

Comment: You are right. I should set pool as 1. What if there is a function stuck in the pool? I am curious. Will it go to the 2nd pool if I set pool as 2?

Comment: A Pool is just a way of distributing work to **multiple** worker Processes and gathering back up the results. I'm not sure what you mean by "stuck", but there is no fail-over type functionality between processes in a Pool. Changing the Pool to 1 will work, but in my opinion defeats the purpose of using Pool in the first place.  Just use Process.

Comment: I mean block or break in the pool. And also what if I want to keep the child task in the pool and follow the query. The one need to wait the one ahead of it.

Comment: I think you asking a different question. Unfortunately, I don't understand it. If I helped with the first question, please accept my answer and post your new question as a separate ask with more details, example code, etc.